# Wordpress plugin modification alerts

Tags: wordpress

I am using Wordpress and have Wordfence (free) watching over my site to make sure people aren't doing anything they shouldn't be doing. I recently got an email from Wordfence warning me about modified plugin files and I'm wondering if this is something I should be worried about? I don't think I've ever received an email before just doing my normal plugin updates. Would updates have triggered this? Or is it more?

Wordpress versions and such:

```
-WordPress 4.4.2
-Headway Theme v. 3.8.8
-Wordfence (free) v. 6.0.24
-Google Captcha (reCAPTCHA) by BestWebSoft v. 1.22 (this is on the login page, so it should help block automated attacks...)
-My username is not a generic 'admin' or anything like that, and I have WordFence set to immediately lock out any invalid username login attempts.
-and my password is decently strong.
-I do have other various plugins that are up to date, I just mention the above because they are supposed to help with security.
```

The Message I received was:

```
Alert generated at Thursday 25th of February 2016 at 11:41:32 PM

Warnings:

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/google-captcha/bws_menu/bws_functions.php

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/google-captcha/bws_menu/bws_menu.php

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/google-captcha/bws_menu/css/general_style.css

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/google-captcha/css/gglcptch.css

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/google-captcha/google-captcha.php

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/google-captcha/js/script.js

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/google-captcha/languages/google-captcha-ar.mo

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/google-captcha/languages/google-captcha-ar.po

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/google-captcha/languages/google-captcha-bg_BG.mo

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/google-captcha/languages/google-captcha-bg_BG.po

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/google-captcha/languages/google-captcha-de_DE.mo

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/google-captcha/languages/google-captcha-de_DE.po

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/google-captcha/languages/google-captcha-el.mo

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/google-captcha/languages/google-captcha-el.po

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/google-captcha/languages/google-captcha-es_ES.mo

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/google-captcha/languages/google-captcha-es_ES.po

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/google-captcha/languages/google-captcha-fa_IR.mo

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/google-captcha/languages/google-captcha-fa_IR.po

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/google-captcha/languages/google-captcha-fr_FR.mo

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/google-captcha/languages/google-captcha-fr_FR.po

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/google-captcha/languages/google-captcha-hi.mo

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/google-captcha/languages/google-captcha-hi.po

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/google-captcha/languages/google-captcha-it_IT.mo

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/google-captcha/languages/google-captcha-it_IT.po

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/google-captcha/languages/google-captcha-pl_PL.mo

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/google-captcha/languages/google-captcha-pl_PL.po

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/google-captcha/languages/google-captcha-pt_BR.mo

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/google-captcha/languages/google-captcha-pt_BR.po

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/google-captcha/languages/google-captcha-ru_RU.mo

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/google-captcha/languages/google-captcha-ru_RU.po

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/google-captcha/languages/google-captcha-uk.mo

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/google-captcha/languages/google-captcha-uk.po

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/google-captcha/languages/google-captcha-zh_TW.mo

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/google-captcha/languages/google-captcha-zh_TW.po

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/google-captcha/readme.txt

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/google-captcha/screenshot-5.png

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/google-captcha/screenshot-6.png

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/google-captcha/screenshot-7.png

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/google-captcha/screenshot-8.png

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/jetpack/_inc/jetpack-jitm.js

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/jetpack/_inc/lib/admin-pages/class.jetpack-landing-page.php

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/jetpack/_inc/lib/markdown/gfm.php

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/jetpack/class.jetpack-modules-list-table.php

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/jetpack/class.jetpack-network.php

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/jetpack/class.jetpack.php

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/jetpack/class.json-api-endpoints.php

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/jetpack/class.json-api.php

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/jetpack/class.photon.php

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/jetpack/css/jetpack-admin.css.map

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/jetpack/functions.opengraph.php

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/jetpack/functions.photon.php

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/jetpack/jetpack.php

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/jetpack/json-endpoints/class.wpcom-json-api-delete-media-endpoint.php

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/jetpack/json-endpoints/class.wpcom-json-api-delete-media-v1-1-endpoint.php

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/jetpack/json-endpoints/class.wpcom-json-api-get-site-endpoint.php

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/jetpack/json-endpoints/class.wpcom-json-api-post-endpoint.php

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/jetpack/json-endpoints/class.wpcom-json-api-post-v1-1-endpoint.php

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/jetpack/json-endpoints/class.wpcom-json-api-sharing-buttons-endpoint.php

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/jetpack/json-endpoints/class.wpcom-json-api-update-post-endpoint.php

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/jetpack/json-endpoints/class.wpcom-json-api-update-post-v1-1-endpoint.php

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/jetpack/json-endpoints/class.wpcom-json-api-update-post-v1-2-endpoint.php

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/jetpack/json-endpoints.php

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/jetpack/locales.php

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/jetpack/modules/contact-form/grunion-contact-form.php

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/jetpack/modules/custom-post-types/comics.php

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/jetpack/modules/custom-post-types/js/many-items.js

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/jetpack/modules/custom-post-types/portfolios.php

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/jetpack/modules/custom-post-types/testimonial.php

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/jetpack/modules/latex.php

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/jetpack/modules/minileven.php

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/jetpack/modules/module-headings.php

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/jetpack/modules/module-info.php

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/jetpack/modules/publicize/ui.php

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/jetpack/modules/related-posts/jetpack-related-posts.php

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/jetpack/modules/related-posts/related-posts.js

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/jetpack/modules/shortcodes/archives.php

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/jetpack/modules/shortcodes/flickr.php

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/jetpack/modules/shortcodes/instagram.php

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/jetpack/modules/shortcodes/presentations.php

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/jetpack/modules/shortcodes/scribd.php

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/jetpack/modules/shortcodes/slideshare.php

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/jetpack/modules/shortcodes/soundcloud.php

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/jetpack/modules/shortcodes/ted.php

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/jetpack/modules/shortcodes/twitter-timeline.php

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/jetpack/modules/shortcodes/vimeo.php

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/jetpack/modules/shortcodes/wufoo.php

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/jetpack/modules/stats.php

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/jetpack/modules/theme-tools/random-redirect.php

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/jetpack/modules/theme-tools/site-logo/js/site-logo-control.js

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/jetpack/modules/videopress/videopress.php

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/jetpack/modules/widget-visibility/widget-conditions/widget-conditions.js

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/jetpack/modules/widget-visibility/widget-conditions.php

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/jetpack/modules/widgets/contact-info.php

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/jetpack/modules/widgets/top-posts.php

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/jetpack/modules/widgets/wordpress-post-widget.php

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/jetpack/readme.txt

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/jetpack/views/admin/my-jetpack-page.php

* Modified plugin file: wp-content/plugins/youtube-channel/readme.txt
```

Is there anywhere I can check to see what or why they were modified? Or what IP made the changes or anything like that? I am the only one with access to the site, as in I don't have any friends or family members or co-workers that can also make changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not the one making the changes you should investigate the situation. There can be a possibility that you site has been hacked. I am also a user of WordFence and i review any notification I get

Comment: The only modifications I do are updates through the update tool in the WP dashboard. I don't make any file changes outside of that. How do I go about investigating further? What steps would you take from here?

Comment: Check the files for any malicious code, remove the plugins and reinstall them if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

If I were you, I wouldn't bother with something like Wordfence. Since you aren't able to understand how the tool works, what benifit do you perceive you're getting from it? As for this report, it looks like some kind of cache is going on. I'd bet huge money this is not a virus, or anything malicous. It's too many files.